# Try...catch loop not catching exception

Tags: java

When the program is run, the catch is not catching an error when a negative number is entered or a letter.  The program runs fine otherwise and there are no errors with anything else.  It is just the catch not catching when an incorrect input is entered.

```
 for (int customer=0; customer<numberOfCustomers; customer++) {
                try {
                    // get amount used by customer as String, convert to double
                    GBused = Double.valueOf(Accounts[customer][USED]);

                    // compute bill based on the customer's plan selection
                    switch (Accounts[customer][SELECTION]) {
                        case "Plan-A":
                            bill = computeBill (GBused, PLAN[A][LIMIT], PLAN[A][PRICE]);
                            break;
                        case "Plan-B":
                            bill = computeBill (GBused, PLAN[B][LIMIT], PLAN[B][PRICE]);
                            break;
                        case "Plan-C":
                            bill = computeBill (GBused, PLAN[C][LIMIT], PLAN[C][PRICE]);
                            break;
                        case "Plan-D":
                            bill = computeBill (GBused, PLAN[D][LIMIT], PLAN[D][PRICE]);
                            break;
                        default:
                            bill = 0.00;
                            break;
                    }
                    // convert the bill to a String and save into the array
                    Accounts[customer][BILL] = String.valueOf(bill);                
                } // end of try               
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println ("Values for GB used must be numeric");               
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no exception being thrown. You need to check for valid values at the input. For characters, there is type casting and the `ASCII` value of the character is used.

Comment: I can show you the whole program if you want, it is a little long.  But the number input is taken and put in to the array to be used for calculations later and for an output for data usage for a cell phone

Comment: I see. In which line do you expect the exception?

Comment: In the method above I have the code for the user to enter input values for each of the people in the array.  The number entered then then moved to the code I posted to calculate the bill according to the cell plan the person has.  So if the number that comes down from the first method is a negative is where I want the exception

Comment: So the exception is actually being thrown in the `computeBill()` method? Can you add the code for that method?

Comment: It's not letting me enter the code correctly for some reason I'm not sure why

Comment: 1. Make sure the `computeBill()` method is throwing the exception up the stack trace. So, add a throws statement to its signature.
2. Make sure you are catching the current exception.

Comment: So add a throw in the next method to toss it back up to the catch for it to catch it?

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that the exception is being thrown in the `computeBill()` method, so you need to add a `throws` statement to its signature, or you can add the `try-catch` block in that method itself.

Comment: How would I go about adding it to the current method to make the catch, actually catch?  Add the throw in there?

Comment: I think I need to see your code for further understanding.

Comment: Hmm can you move the convo to a chat or is there another way I can send it to you?  Or I could post the whole code in a new post

Comment: Yeah sure, a chat would be fine.

Comment: My rep isn't high enough to start one.  Are you able to or should I find another way to get it to you?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "(Exception e)" to catch any possible exception you may get.